# Make vector of each column of a dataframe and return the vectors in a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, vector

I have a dataframe like:

```
df<-data.frame(x=1:5,y=6:10,z=11:15)



 x  y  z
1 1  6 11
2 2  7 12
3 3  8 13
4 4  9 14
5 5 10 15
```

Now I would like to create a list `new_list`  where every element is a single column of as a vector.

This would look like:

```
str(new_list)
list of 3
$ : num[1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
$ : num[1:5] 6 7 8 9 10
$ : num[1:5] 11 12 13 14 15
```

I tried:

```
new_list <-lapply(df,c)
```

but this only returend

```
list of 3
$ : num[1:5] 1
$ : num[1:5] 6
$ : num[1:5] 11
```

Note: I hope my goal is clear. If not plese let me know.

Comment: A data frame is already a list of the columns... if you tell us why you want to do this we may be able to help more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `c`.

```
l <- lapply(df, c)
str(l)
# List of 3
#  $ x: int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
#  $ y: int [1:5] 6 7 8 9 10
#  $ z: int [1:5] 11 12 13 14 15
```

or `as.list`.

```
l <- as.list(df)
str(l)
# List of 3
#  $ x: int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
#  $ y: int [1:5] 6 7 8 9 10
#  $ z: int [1:5] 11 12 13 14 15
```

Comment: `unname(as.list(df))`

Comment: @Roland why bother with `unname()`?

Comment: In the example you provided the list elements are not named.

Comment: @GregorThomas Why bother removing the class attribute (as you commented under the question)? I only intended to supplement the small step to derive OP's expected result.

Answer (score 3):

Using `identity()`

```
lapply(df, identity)
```

Just modifying the attributes and class:

```
new_list <- unclass(df)
attr(new_list, "row.names") <- NULL
```

Or

```
new_list <- df
class(new_list) <- "list" # NULL also works but is not as clear
attr(new_list, "row.names") <- NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

A `data.frame` is just a list with some additional attributes. The simplest way to turn a `data.frame` into a list with the structure you have requested is to remove all the attributes.

If you need to create a new object, you can copy the existing one and then strip it.

```
new_list <- df

attributes(new_list) <- NULL

> str(new_list)
List of 3
 $ : int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
 $ : int [1:5] 6 7 8 9 10
 $ : int [1:5] 11 12 13 14 15
```

However, this is usually done "in the wild" using `as.list()`, even though this retains variable names and has some additional overhead.